# Combination of 4 digits 1 digit is repeated

Tags: probability, combinations

Im trying to get how many 4 digit integers can we get if we have exactly 2 similar integers.

My attempt till now is that we can have 6 combinations for the repeated digits:
d1d2, d1d3, d1d4, d2d3, d2d4, and d3d4.

so we can have 6.(10.9.8) numbers
I still need to subtract the numbers that have zero as the 1st digit inorder not to be a 3-digit number.
so if zero is the first digit we have 1.10.9 possibilities. Shall I multiply this number by 6 or not.

I can feel that im missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two different kinds of four digit numbers in which there are exactly two similar digits:

(a) The first digit belongs to the pair of similar digits.

(b) The first digit does not belong to the the pair of similar digits.

Ad (a).

There are $9$ choices for the similar digits ($0$ is excluded; it cannot be the leading digit of our number). Then there are $3$ choices for the place of the other member of the pair. So far we have $9\cdot 3=27$ possibilities. For the remaining two places we may not put the number chosen to be similar but we can use $0$ at least once. So we have $9\cdot8=72$ possibilities. As a total we have $$27\cdot 72=1944$$

possibilities.

Ad (b).

If the first digit does not play a role in forming a pair of similar digits then there are $9$ choices for it because $0$ cannot used here. Then we can choose the place of the similar pair $3$ ways and we still have $9$ possibilities to choose the similar numbers because we can use $0$ now.  For the remaining place we have only $8$ choices. (We cannot use the digit used to be the first one and we cannot use the digit we chose for the pair.) The total is

$$9\cdot 3 \cdot 9 \cdot 8=1944.$$

(a) and (b) together is

$$1944+1944=3888.$$

Answer (score 2):

What you want to subtract instead are the counts of three-digit strings with one $0$ and two other distinct digits and those with a repeated digit but no $0$.  The final answer is

$$(6\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8)-(3\cdot9\cdot8)-(3\cdot9\cdot8)$$